# Edit function not working in CRUD form (Laravel)

Tags: laravel

I've created a CRUD form called 'Groups'. The Create and Delete functions work, but the 'Edit' throws up an error:

> "Undefined variable: group (View:
>   C:\wamp64\www\sites\jointpromote2\resources\views\groups\edit.blade.php

The error points to this line of code:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="group_name" value="<?php echo e($group->group_name); ?>" />
```

I've tried several things but nothing fixes the issue.

Here is my `http/controllers/GroupController.php`

```
    {
        $event = Group::find($id);
        return view('groups.edit', compact('group'));
    }
```

Here's my `database/migrations/create_groups_table.php`

```
 public function down()

{
    Schema::dropIfExists('groups');
}
```

And here's the edit.blade.php

```
@section('main')
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8 offset-sm-2">
        <h1 class="display-3">Update a Group</h1>

        @if ($errors->any())
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <ul>
                @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div>
        <br />
        @endif

        <form method="post" action="{{ route('groups.update', '$group->id') }}">
            @method('PATCH')
            @csrf
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="group_name">Group Name:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="group_name" value="{{ $group->group_name }}" />
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="group_description">Group Description:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="group_description" value="{{ $group->group_description }}" />
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Comment: Can you please show you controller ?

Comment: you mean GroupController.php?

Comment: can you share your GroupController.php code ?

Comment: Sure, but if I copy and paste it here, it will all display on a single line! How do people usually share code in comments?

Comment: Please give space before the paste

Comment: test, test  test,

Comment: I tried every combination of single and double spaces but it's all displayed on a single line.

Answer (score 0):

You are using "compact" method in wrong way.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php

try with this

```
{
  $event = Group::find($id);
  return view('groups.edit', compact($event));
}
```

Comment: Thank you but this didn't work. I implemented the solution zlatan suggested, but it only half fixed the issue. When I added your 'compact($event));' in the code it reverted to not working at all?

Answer (score 0):

You're passing wrong variable from your `GroupController` to your `edit.blade.php` view. Change your `GroupController` to this:

```
    {
        $group= Group::find($id);
        return view('groups.edit', compact('group'));
    }
```

All should be working now.

Comment: Of course, I had the wrong name, thank you. I implemented this and it now diverted to the edit page where I am able to edit, but clicking 'update' takes me to an error page?

Comment: The error is 'Creating default object from empty value'.

The web URL I am lead to after clicking 'update' is:  http://localhost/sites/jointpromote2/public/groups/%24group-%3Eid

It seems something is wrong with this line:  $group->group_name =  $request->get('group_name');

Comment: Can you post your controller code where you're updating your records?

Comment: Sure, but if I post in this comment section it will all be on one line? How should I post it so it's easy for you to read? (thank you for your help)

Comment: The error is specifying this code:  
`public function update(Request $request, $id)  
    {  
        $request->validate([  
            'group_name' => 'required',  
            'group_description' => 'required',  
        ]);  
<br>
        $group = group::find($id);  
        $group->group_name =  $request->get('group_name');  
        $group->group_description = $request->get('group_description');  
        $group->save();  
        return redirect('/groups')->with('success', 'group updated!');  
    } 
`,

Comment: I think some of your input fields are not getting passed to your request.

Comment: Admittedly I'm a bit of a newby. Can you suggest how I can check this?

Comment: You can do dd($request) on top of your update function, and check if all input fields are there when you submit them.

Comment: I've just been Googling "how to do a dd($request)"! Is this something I do in command prompt or in my code editor?

Comment: You use it in a code (in this example, on top of your update function). What it does is basically gives you the output of the given variable.

Comment: When I put the  dd($request) directly above "public function update(Request $request, $id)" I get syntax error, unexpected 'dd'. I don't know exactly where to put dd($request).

Comment: Put it inside that function

Comment: Thanks, but wherever I put it, my code editor turns the text red (something wrong). For example, this is one attempt "public function update(Request $request, $id, dd($request))", this is clearly wrong.

Comment: I've now complied this into a new question more specific to this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57926924/what-am-i-doing-wrong-with-dd-request

Answer (score 0):

Your variable name is `event` but you are compacting `group` and using `group` variable in blade. Change the variable name in controller and everything will be fine.

```
public function edit($id) {
    $group = Group::find($id);
    return view('groups.edit', compact('group'));
}
```

Comment: Well spotted! I implemented this and it now diverts successfully to the edit page where I am able to edit, but clicking 'update' takes me to an error page?

Answer (score 0):

You write action is in the wrong way. Try copy and paste below code

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('groups.update', 
$group->id) }}">
```

You have to remove '.' from $group->id

Comment: Thank you. I redid the whole thing using a different tutorial and it now works! I will take note of your comment for future.

Comment: if you find help please vote clicking on the arrow up sign, so that other can find useful by seeing this post.

Comment: Done. Although votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Comment: Ok no problem 